# Multidimensional array from json android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have this json here:

```
[
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "Item Description": "Data removed for protection",
            "Link": "Data removed for protection",
            "Image": "Data removed for protection",
            "Valid From": "Data removed for protection",
            "Valid To": "Data removed for protection"
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "Item Description": "Data removed for protection",
            "Link": "Data removed for protection",
            "Image": "Data removed for protection",
            "Valid From": "Data removed for protection",
            "Valid To": "Data removed for protection"
        },
{
            "ID": "4",
            "Item Description": "Data removed for protection",
            "Link": "Data removed for protection",
            "Image": "Data removed for protection",
            "Valid From": "Data removed for protection",
            "Valid To": "Data removed for protection"
        }
    ]
```

So I download this to a `JSONObject` called `jArray`. I then turn this into a `JSONArray` like so:

```
JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(jArray);
```

However, whenever I try to access it like so: `json_array[0][0]` the IDE throws an error on it and says:  `Array type expected; found: 'org.json.JSONArray'`.

Now, dont get me wrong, but shouldn't a `JSONArray` behave in the same way to access the multidimensional aspect?

Comment: how can u come to conclusion that 'JSONArray' Gives Multi dimension Array as array[][] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSONArray` and normal java arrays are not the same.`JSONArray` is a different java object. @Kon's answer provides basic idea of `JSONArray`.

If you want to access the data from your `JSONArray`, you can loop through it to get each `JSONObject` and then retrieve data from there something like

```
JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(jArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length() ; i++) {
              try{
                    JSONObject object1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    int id = object1.getInt("ID");
                    String itemDescription = object1.getString("Item Description");     
                    String link = object1.getString("Link");
                    .....//and so on        
                 }
              catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not behave in the same way as a multidimensional array.

This is because `json_array` is not an array, it is a different Java object. Only arrays can be accessed with this specific syntax you've shown above. You will need to look into the documentation for this class to see how to access the information you want. It should provide clear and well-documented methods for getting what you need.

You wouldn't want this syntax to allow you to access the array which backs your class anyways. This would be a breach of encapsulation and be poor design in general.

A good starting point is here http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html